# I need to decompose the image of a cat into geometric shapes

Tags: c#, inheritance, console, polymorphism, hierarchy

I recently had homework to program the appearance and movement of the ship in the console. The task was such "Build a class hierarchy to draw an image of ship. When building your own hierarchy, follow the principles of encapsulation, inheritance and polymorphism. The ship must be able to move in a certain direction". Now I need the same thing, but with a cat.

A cat is a complex creature and I have no idea how to draw it in the console
[*Here's my repository for the ship in console*](https://github.com/Smed3/ConsoleShip) and
[Programm output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2lO3.png)

Comment: So, what is the question for us? Is this assignment too hard? Got any code?

Comment: I figured it out. That's what I meant: https://github.com/Smed3/Lab6. I will be grateful if you check the code